# I think I discovered a bug with isNaN()

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript mechanics and I believe I just stumbled across a bug with `isNaN()`.

Here is the test code.

```
var x = "1000";

Answer = isNaN(x);
console.log(Answer);
```

The console log returns "false" which indicates that Javascript looks at "1000" as a number. I thought that anything inside `" "` was considered a string.  Evidently not always.  If I'm wrong maybe somebody has some insight that can set me straight.

Comment: NaN has a very specific meaning with regards to floating point number representation. isNaN only tests for that.

Comment: Dangit thanks!  I searched for isNaN and that thread didn't come up.  That thread has the answer.

Comment: I haven't read the post, but I'm pretty sure javascript recognizes strings as numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, it's a feature, not a bug.

> When the argument to the `isNaN` function is not of type Number, the value is first coerced to a Number. The resulting value is then tested to determine whether it is `NaN`.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: Another noteworthy distinction: `Number.isNaN` does not do this coercion. `isNaN('A') === true`, while `Number.isNaN('A') === false`.